# How to fake keyboard input to bash, on requrest?

Tags: bash

I'm running serialized bash commands inside bash script to download (legally!) a few videos through sub-script using stream. The subscript starts with asking what quality to download (press keyb 1-4) and then goes on downloading for a few minutes.

How can I fake pressing 2 after question so that I can leave computer running without any further input until finished?

Answer (score 2):

This will send `2` to the script like you typed `2` on the keyboard

```
./the-script.sh <<EOF
2
EOF
```